# Gradle Version Replacing characters

Tags: gradle, versioning, rpm

I am using nebula release plugin, which generates -SNAPSHOTS for snapshot builds, also using the nebula ospackage plugin to buildRpm, I am trying to use the same version as of project for RPM as well, but rpm complains about - as illegal character, Is there a way to get this fix keeping the same nomenclature, i know the rpm nomenclature standards doesn't allow this.

Can I do something like in build.gradle project.version.toString().replace("_",".")

Comment: Did you try what you're suggesting? Did you get any errors?

Comment: The nebula ospackage plugin allows you to set package version, you can transform gradle project version however you want and use that as your ospackage version.

Comment: RaGe, I hope you must have read my whole comment, I am using nebule release plugin as well, which uses -SNAPSHOT on itself... its about combining it with ospackage pluing i am not able to use the same project version ... so if i am releasing snapshot it has to be -SNAPSHOT and i wan to keep the same nomenclature, the error i am getting during buildRpm cos it treats - as illegal character. So i was thinking if somehow i can replace that character as i said above. Yes i tried project.version.toString().replace("_","."), it says no method found.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

If `project.version` is where the `nebula-release` plugin stores the generated version string, then you should be able to use:

```
project.version.replace('-','.')
```

(`toString()` is not necessary, but should work with it included too.)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with following work around:

```
if (project.version.toString().contains("-")){
    version = project.version.toString().replaceAll("-", ".")
} else {
    version = project.version
}
```